# Access Asp.net web api over https protocol

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net application and I have hosted that in IIS over https.
I have a API controller in my application. 
I am calling the controller from $.ajax like this.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "json",
            url: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/api/Task/GetTasks") %>?taskId=" + taskId + '&taskRevisionId=' + taskRevisionId,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,

            success: function (data) {                
                 alert('sucess');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('failed');
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        });
```

and my API controller method like this

```
 public class TaskController : ApiController
    {
 [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public string GetTaskOwnersAndTask(Guid taskId, Guid taskRevisionId)
        {
            return "Test";
        }
}
```

The service call working over http protocol, but not in https

It says, 404 not found error while accessing it over https protocol.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does the site itself load up over HTTPS?
do you get any browser warnings or errors about the HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, our site loads over HTTPS, but I am not getting any error message while launching the application over HTTPS.